# box around TikZ graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I've this code

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={minimum width = 3 cm, minimum height = 1 cm, fill=green},
  node distance=2mm
]
  \node(frontend) {Frontend};
  \node(nginx) [below=of frontend] {NGINX};
  \node(debian) [below=of nginx] {Debian};
  \node(backend) [right=of frontend] {Backend};
  \node(nodejs) [below=of backend] {NodeJS};
  \node(coreos) [below=of nodejs] {CoreOS};
  \node(database) [right=of backend] {Database};
  \node(postgresql) [below=of database] {PostgreSQL};
  \node(alpine) [below=of postgresql] {Alpine};
  \node(docker) [below=of coreos,minimum width = 9.4 cm] {Docker engine};
  \node(hostos) [below=of docker,minimum width = 9.4 cm] {Host Operating System};
  \node(physical-server) [below=of hostos,minimum width = 9.4 cm] {Physical server};

\end{document}
```

which generates

[image]

I want a box around three small verticle nodes (e.g. Frontend, NGINX, Debian). And programmatic color scheme would be appreciated.

Comment: To solve the alignment issue, use `\node(alpine) [below=of postgresql] {Alpine};
  \node(docker) [below=of coreos,minimum width = 9.4 cm] {Docker engine};`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the "programmatic color scheme". What is your expected output?

Comment: For the box around three of the green boxes, you can ues the `fit` library in combination with something like `\node[draw, fill=none, inner sep=1mm,fit=(frontend) (debian)] {};`.

Comment: For the small vertex nodes it may makes sense to use a matrix.

Comment: It would be boring to manually change color for each of the objects. By color scheme I mean something like - adding shades. BTW, could you provide a solution using matrix? @leandriis

Comment: Is the color scheme supposed to follow any logic? e.g. lighter shades of a base color for every following row...?

Comment: Doesn't matter as long as some grouping is clear especially among the set of small objects (eg, group1: Frontend, NGINX, Debian, group2: Backend, NodeJS, CoreOS) @leandriis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, matrix}
\colorlet{mybasecolor}{green}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix(table)[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep =2mm,
  column sep = 2mm,
  nodes={minimum width = 3 cm, minimum height = 1 cm, fill=mybasecolor},
  column 2/.style={nodes={fill=mybasecolor!50}},
  column 3/.style={nodes={fill=mybasecolor!25}},
  ] 
  {Frontent & Backend & Database    \\
   NGINX    & NodeJS  & PostgreSQL  \\
   Debian   & CoreOS  & Alpine      \\
  };
  \node[draw, fill=none, inner sep=1mm,fit=(table-1-1.north west) (table-3-1.south east)] {};
  \tikzset{every node/.append style={minimum width = 9.4 cm, minimum height = 1 cm, fill=mybasecolor!75!black},
  node distance=2mm,}
  \node(docker) [below=of table] {Docker engine};
  \node(hostos) [below=of docker] {Host Operating System};
  \node(physical-server) [below=of hostos] {Physical server};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Could you think of a nice way to put rectangles around other two groups as well? @leandriis

Comment: @moazzem: Sure, you can use the same approach. Just change the parameters of `fit` accordingly. (`table-3-1.south east` corresponds to the `south east` edge of the cell in column `1` and row `3` of the matrix named `table`.)