# Block diagram with subdivided blocks in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to obtain something similar to the following sketch:
[image: schema]

The problem is how to draw the node `E` with the right dimensions to cover the four nodes below.

What I have right now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    block/.style={
      rectangle,
      rounded corners,
      inner sep=1em
    }
  ]
    
    \path node[block,white,fill=jeans] (mathsat) {MathSAT\strut};
    \path (mathsat.east) ++(2pt,0) node[block,anchor=west,white,fill=jeans] 
      (z3) {Z3\strut};
    \path (z3.east) ++(2pt,0) node[block,anchor=west,white,fill=jeans] 
      (minisat) {MiniSAT\strut};
    \path (minisat.east) ++(2pt,0) node[block,anchor=west,white,fill=jeans] 
      (cmsat) {CryptoMiniSAT\strut};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which just draws the four blocks below.

How do I draw a node above the four blocks of the exact width?

Comment: Some related questions on similar diagrams: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/523175/134144 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/521237/134144

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fit` and `matrix` libraries are really helping. Note that you have to use `\hphantom` on your first two rows if you want the fitting to behave properly. If you chose to have all columns of the same size, this will not be mandatory anymore.

[image: matrix of nodes and fit]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{block/.style={
            rounded corners, fill=cyan,text=white,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}}
    
        \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
                     nodes in empty cells,
                     nodes={rounded corners,
                            minimum height=1cm, 
                            inner sep=1em,
                            outer sep=0pt},
                     column sep=1mm,
                        row sep=1mm,
                        row 1/.style = {nodes={minimum height=2cm}},
                        row 2/.style = {nodes={minimum height=3cm}},
                        row 3/.style = {nodes={fill=cyan, text=white}},
                     ]
        {   
            \hphantom{MathSAT} & \hphantom{Z3} & \hphantom{MiniSAT} & \hphantom{CryptoMiniSAT}\\
            \hphantom{MathSAT} & \hphantom{Z3} & \hphantom{MiniSAT} & \hphantom{CryptoMiniSAT}\\        MathSAT & Z3 & MiniSAT & CryptoMiniSAT \\
            };
        
        \node[block,fit=(m-1-1)(m-1-4)]{YOUR F NODE};
        \node[block,fit=(m-2-1)(m-2-4)]{YOUR E NODE};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for! I should have thought about the fit library!